# How to know which sdb is a USB pendrive?

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, mount, usb-drive

I wrote a script which formats USB pendrive and place media on it.
*It helps people in a library getting a bunch of HTML and media on it to browse historical data (official version).*

All my script do the job well (formatting, mounting, copying, unmounting, say "goodbye"). But one point: how to know which device should I browse.

One only condition: there is still MAXimum 1 pendrive plugged in.

There is generally 3 people by day comming to plug their (USB!) stick in the machine (it looks like a buck-machine for credit card).

**My Question**
Please help, I dont know what to do to say my script :

> Hey, the only USB device is /dev/sdX1

Or

> Hey, no USB pendrive in my I/O.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` and `awk`

```
#!/bin/bash

# your code ...

# The name of your MAXimum 1 drive in /media/$USER
maximum1="MAXimum 1"

if [ -z "$(find /media/$USER/ -maxdepth 1 ! -path /media/$USER/ -type d |\
    awk '! /'"$maximum1"'/')" ]
then
    echo "Hey, the only USB device is $maximum1"
else
    echo "Hey, no USB pendrive in my I/O."
fi

# your code ...
```

---

*Example*

```
% ls -laog /media/$USER

total 24
drwxr-x---+ 3  4096 Aug 20 15:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  5  4096 Aug 18 08:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 16384 Jan  1  1970 STORE N GO

% maximum1="STORE N GO"; if [ -z "$(find /media/$USER/ -maxdepth 1 ! -path /media/$USER/ -type d | awk '! /'"$maximum1"'/')" ]; then echo "Hey, the only USB device is $maximum1"; else echo "Hey, no USB pendrive in my I/O."; fi
Hey, the only USB device is STORE N GO

% maximum1="NOT STORE N GO"; if [ -z "$(find /media/$USER/ -maxdepth 1 ! -path /media/$USER/ -type d | awk '! /'"$maximum1"'/')" ]; then echo "Hey, the only USB device is $maximum1"; else echo "Hey, no USB pendrive in my I/O."; fi
Hey, no USB pendrive in my I/O.
```

Comment: And when is asap? =)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has neat command `udisksctl` which allows looking up information with the `info` option on a block device specified with the `-b` flag.

Now, if we scan the output of `udiskctl` for each block device from a to z, and search for the 'usb' string in it, we can be sure it is a USB device.

Bellow is a script that does exactly that:

```
#!/bin/bash

FOUND=0
for var in {a..z}; do 

    udisksctl info -b /dev/sd$var 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'usb'; 
    if [ $(echo $?) -eq 0 ]; then 
        echo " FOUND USB DEVICE /dev/sd$var "; 
        FOUND=1
    fi 


done 

if [ $FOUND -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "NO USB DEVICES FOUND"
fi
```

There we have `FOUND` flag, that just serves the purpose of printing "NO USB DEVICES FOUND" if... well... if no USB devices are found! Otherwise, if we find at least one USB device , we set that flag to 1 and ignore it.

Here's sample output with two USBs plugged in and then removed:

```
CURRENT DIR:[/home/xieerqi]
$ ./bin/sh/findusb.sh                                                                                                                         
 FOUND USB DEVICE /dev/sdb 
 FOUND USB DEVICE /dev/sdc 

CURRENT DIR:[/home/xieerqi]
$ ./bin/sh/findusb.sh                                                                                                                         
NO USB DEVICES FOUND
```

Feel free to modify this script to suit your need.

Comment: Seems to be better than my answer =)

Comment: @A.B. yours is fine as long as no-one mounts anything like a hard drive partition   under `/media/$USER/`.  Assuming that only admin can mount partitions there - I'd say it's alright. Also, if admin manually mounts a usb on another folder, say `/mnt`, then there's problem.